# How does a flash of light appear to a high speed observer

Tags: speed-of-light, relativity

Imagine two dark chambers separated by a light-proof partition each with a 30m high ceiling. Chamber A has a letter A painted in white on its black ceiling, chamber B has the letter B also in white on its ceiling. 
A camera mounted on a trolley passes between the two at great speed. As it enters chamber A its shutter is opened and it triggers a bright flash, but in just under 0.1 microseconds, before the light from the flash has reached the ceiling, the camera passes though the partition into the pitch black chamber B where its shutter is closed a second later.

My question is:
 Will the camera capture the letter A, the letter B or neither?

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, your question doesn't involve relativity. Its simply just about speed of light. And does "**great speed**" mean c ?

Comment: I think it does involve relativity as the camera is moving very quickly so that its speed relative to the speed of light is significant. Also, the reason for my question is that the speed of light, according to the theory of relativity is independent of the speed of the observer.

Comment: neither, as there is no light entering the camera

Comment: @brucesmitherson he mentioned every chamber to be dark....I guess dark means 100% dark

Comment: You have not provided enough information.  The speed of the camera, the distance that it rolls through each room, the distance between the flash unit and the ceiling, the duration of the flash.  They're all going to be part of the answer.

Comment: My thinking was - if the speed of light is independent of the camera then as the camera passes through the partition there should be a dome of light around it about to hit the ceiling.

Comment: @james large - The only significance about the speed of the camera was that it had passed to chamber B before the light hit the ceiling in chamber A. I should specified the flash as being more of an instantaneous spark.

Comment: OK, I misread your question.  I understood that you meant for the flash duration to be infinitessimal, but I was thinking that the partition did not reach the ceiling, and that the flash gun would illuminate the ceiling of both rooms.  If the flash only illuminates room A, and the camera has moved out of room A before the reflected light has time to reach the lens, then the answer should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The camera will not capture either letter because:
1. The light emitted into chamber A had not returned to the camera for capture/exposure/imaging before the camera moved to chamber B.
2  Chamber B is dark, so there is no light to reflect off the white B on the ceiling to be reflected/captured/exposed/imaged in the camera.

Comment: Except that if the speed of light as observed by the camera is constant, the energy from the light can be seen as tracking the path of the camera (from its perspective) and following it into chamber B.

Comment: Let's visualize your photon stream as a very short segment of light (like a squirt of water).  That short segment is emitted from the flash, but doesn't even strike the ceiling in Chamber A before the camera is in Chamber B.  There's no way an image can be formed without the reflected light returning to the camera (not to mention the time needed for film/ccd exposure).  Even though the speed of light is constant, I do not think that light can be seen as tracking the camera (not from the camera's pov nor from a remote pov).  It's just a short segment on its own path--free from the camera.

Comment: So although the flash of light appears to the camera to spread out from itself at exactly the same rate as it does from its fixed point of emmission, it can't really because that would mean the light was in two places at the same time and that's impossible isn't it? Maybe time/length dilation can explain it but I'm not convinced.

Comment: How do you arrive at the conclusion " that would mean the light was in two places at the same time and that's impossible isn't it?" The flash emanates from the moving camera, right? Is the light that is emitted from the flash *a continuous light* that occurs on both sides of the barrier or does it just emit while in chamber A for a very short period of time & not emit any light when moving into chamber B?

Comment: In order for my point to be valid, the light is assumed to be an instantaneous (very short sharp) spark in chamber A close to the camera at the time of emmission. Then if we accept the speed of light as being constant to all observers regardless of their velocities then I think it's clear the light must be in one place wrt the camera and in a different place wrt its point of emmission as the camera travels to a new position.

Comment: It seems to me that the light is exactly where the light is at any given moment of time--regardless of any perspective.  It's position in space isn't different for each observer or from any specific pov.

Comment: I see - you must be an emmission theorist.

Comment: Not at all. I just think the problem here is merely trying to visualize very fast things and describe them clearly from one or more povs.  Basically, I think if we freeze-frame, describe, & step through the events in time, we'd have a better way of imagining what is happening. So, with in mind, I'd describe things this way:
1.  T1 light begins to emit from the flash.  It moves away from the camera & falls behind the camera as the camera advances along it's path.

Comment: 2.  T2 more light is emitted.  It does the same thing as the first bit of light, but it trails the first bit of light a bit (i.e. it has a shorter distance from it's position to the camera than the 1st bit of light).  The 1st bit of light begins to expand/spread out from its initial core (because that what light does as it moves though the atomosphere).
3.  The process continues until no more light is emitted from the flash.
4.  When all of the light has been emitted & we freeze it in time (before it reaches the ceiling), we can imagine it from whatever pov/s that we choose.

Comment: 5.  From the camera's pov, the light is above & behind it. It appears narrower at the bottom & wider at the top (due to the spread of the light at the top).  Its shape is a bit like a very narrowly sliced wedge of cheese.  The older light is also spread out wider (perpendicular to the camera travel path) than the newer light.
6.  From the side view (perpendicular to the line the camera travels), the light appears to resemble the side of a stair case along the path of the camera.
7.  From the top view the older light appears to be wider than the newer light.

Comment: 8.  In general, the group of light quickly falls behind the moving camera along it's path.

Comment: Imagine a very short very sharp flash of light emmitted while the camera is in very close proximity to its source. A very thin dome of light spreads out from the source at the speed of light. It also spreads out from the camera at the speed of light in all directions thus the dome effectively has two centres, one fixed and the other moving (wrt the source).

Comment: What does this "...while the camera is in very close proximity to its source." mean? The flash device is moving with the camera, correct? What causes you to conclude that the emitted light is "dome' shaped? How does your light spread out from the source (flash device) and also from the camera? Your light only emanates from the flash device that is also in motion with the camera, correct?  Try to imagine your flash of light in nano/femto seconds as if it is frozen in space above the flash device & camera aperture.  Also, what percentage of the speed of light is the camera moving?

Comment: If it's a very short sharp burst of light it doesn't much matter where the flash is, but it would have been clearer if I had stated it as being fixed to the floor in chamber A. The speed of the camera is not vitally important but would probably be in the order of c/30 if it manages to cross from one chamber to another in 1 microsecond..

Comment: Even in that case, though the light will pass above the moving camera aperture (because it is much faster than the moving camera), it will not have had sufficient time to reach (much less reflect off) the ceiling to be useful for imaging purposes.  You can consider the light from which ever pov you wish, however if the light does not reflect off the letter A or enter into Chamber B, and enter into the camera aperture, then no image will be captured by the camera.

Comment: Sorry DIYser but I was really hoping for an answer based on Einsteinian Physics not Neutonian Phisics. One that does not assume the movement of photons out of a lamp to be similar to that of cannon balls from a cannon.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you. My crude imagery was intended more as a basic image than a thing of beauty/elegance--and as an aid in essentially explaining my position. I still do not see how your position could be true.

Answer (score 0):

Neither it moved faster than the photons coming off the ceiling in A so it recorded no image and when it entered the B room no flash was executed so it could not capture the B image.

Comment: I agree with your explanation for A but not entirely convinced about B. The reason I'm not convinced is because I have doubts about the relationship between matter and energy.

Comment: Is it because of the probability of the photon being in more than one place at a time. Perhaps their is a photon tunneling argument that could work that allows some of the photons to from A actually to pass into room B. Perhaps you could look at that more closely.

Comment: That's interesting but not quite what I meant. See my comment to DIYser's answer.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you on the energy of the light following the camera into B. Can you explain?

Comment: I'll try.. The initial flash results in a dome of light spreading away from the source. But it spreads away from the camera at the same rate while the camera moves into chamber B. So it's as if the expanding dome of energy is tracking the motion of the camera into chamber B.

Comment: Well if the camera is moving at the speed of light some of the photons might actually have high wave probability of being in room B as well as A. {similar to tunneling effect} The length of flash and the dimensions of the dome of light would need to be examined in your case. I think that I am saying in that case that since the camera was moving so fast from room to room it actually sent photons from the flash into both rooms during the course of its transition in location.